# tkinter how to divide frame into parts?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a1E3.jpg)I am making tkinter gui program. In the program, When I clicked button, A pop-up is displayed.
I want to divide pop-up frame into 9 buttons and display image in button.
But in my code, The buttons are joined, not divided.
Below is part of my code. I will wait for your help. Thank you.

```
  def create_window(self):
        window=Toplevel(root2)
        window.geometry("600x600")
        self.galleryframe=Frame(window)
        self.galleryframe.pack()

        self.topgframe=Frame(self.galleryframe,width=600,height=200)
        self.topgframe.pack()

        self.ibutton1=Button(self.topgframe,width=20,height=20)
        try:
            self.image1=PhotoImage(file="/home/som/imagefolder/1.png")
            self.ibutton1.config(image=self.image1)
            self.ibutton1.image=self.image1
        except TclError:
            pass
        self.ibutton1.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.ibutton2=Button(self.topgframe,width=20,height=20)
        try:
            self.image2=PhotoImage(file="/home/som/imagefolder/2.png")
            self.ibutton2.config(image=self.image2)
            self.ibutton2.image=self.image2
        except TclError:
            pass
        self.ibuttom2.pack()

        self.ibutton3=Button(self.topgframe,width=20,height=20)
        try:
            self.image3=PhotoImage(file="/home/som/imagefolder/3.png")
            self.ibutton3.config(image=self.image3)
            self.ibutton3.image=self.image3
        except TclError:
            pass
        self.ibuttom3.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.midgframe=Frame(self.galleryframe,width=600,height=200)
        self.midgframe.pack()

        self.ibutton4=Button(self.midgframe,width=20,height=20)
        try:
            self.image4=PhotoImage(file="/home/som/imagefolder/4.png")
            self.ibutton4.config(image=self.image4)
            self.ibutton4.image=self.image4
        except TclError:
            pass
        self.ibuttom4.pack(side=LEFT)

      ....ibutton5-9 are almost same with upper things.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small typo in your code. Try replacing:

```
self.ibuttom2.pack()
```

with

```
self.ibutton2.pack()   # Same for buttons 3, 4, etc.
```

Comment: If the issue is caused by a simple typographical error, please comment the error and flag to close it as a “simple typographical error”

Comment: @abccd, ok I will do that!